# Catel DependencyInjection Issue

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, catel

I am tyring to using the CreateInstanceWithParametersAndAutoCompletion() to create an instance of a viewmodel that I am going to use with the UIVisualizerService.  One of the constructor parameters that I have is a repository that I have.  This repository has a constructor that takes the connectionStr as a parameter:

```
var repos = new Repository( connectionStr );
```

ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterInstance(repos);

Unfortunately when I attempt to instantiate my MyViewModel() class, the repository is not being found.  I then attempted to instantiate it as follows:

```
var userLoginVm = TypeFactory.Default.CreateInstanceWithParametersAndAutoCompletionWithTag<UserLoginViewModel>( new Repository( connectionStr ));
```

(I have tried this a number of ways, but get the same issue about not being able to inject the repository ).

15:27:32:626 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Creating instance of type 'DesktopTool.ViewModels.UserLoginViewModel' using specific parameters. No constructor found in the cache, so searching for the right one
15:27:32:626 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Checking if constructor 'public ctor(CurrSession pCurrSession, Repository pUserRepos, IUIVisualizerService pVisualService, IMessageService pMsgService)' can be used
15:27:32:628 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Constructor is not valid because value 'xxx.Repository' cannot be used for parameter 'xxx.Repository'

I am about to give up on this.  Any suggestions on how to properly register my repository class so that the injection works properly?

Comment: Can you share the code of `MyViewModel` class?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try the `ViewModelFactory`, which is meant for this kind of stuff.
2. As you can see in the logging, you need to inject **2** parameters

CurrSession pCurrSession, Repository pUserRepos

So you need to specify both pCurrSession and pUserRepos